# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page, mobile / desktop views and layouts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

I've been having a problem lately when trying to show mobile pages:

**The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "head".**

This happens randomly, usually my app works fine, but there's a few times when this exception gets thrown and the user isn't able to see the page.

For my research, it seems that this happens when trying to access mobile views.

I have two different layouts, one for desktop views, and one for mobile views. The desktop layout has a rendering for a section head:

@RenderSection("head", required: false)

while the mobile view does not have such a section.

So, just to clarify, my mobile / desktops views have the following pattern:

- Mobile: views don't have head section, _Layout.Mobile.cshtml does not render head section. Views have a directive Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.Mobile.cshtml".
- Desktop views have head section, _Layout.cshtml renders head section with the following code: @RenderSection("head", required: false).  Views have a directive Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml".

So, it seems that when detecting which view and layout to render, it takes the mobile view but the desktop layout ... or the other way around ...

Does have any kind of experience with such a problem that is able to shed any light?

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody has any idea about this problem?

Comment: After dedicating some time to this, I finally figured what was going on. As it turns out, I was experiencing a known bug in MVC4, in which web page caches are not handled correctly. A fix has been published, there's a library you can download using Nuget that will fix this issue: Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.

Comment: You should add this as an answer and accept it.